# Showing that $A \subset B$ if and only if $\forall x\in X 1_A(x)\leq 1_B(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Good morning,

I'm trying to prove that $A \subset B$ if and only if $1_A(x)\le 1_B(x)$.

$1_A(x)$ and $1_B(x)$ are the indicator functions of subsets A and B.

I tried to proceed analyzing all the different cases. I think I've managed to show that $A \subset B$ when $1_A(x) = 1_B (x)= 1$ and when $1_A(x) = 1_B(x) = 0$.

However, I still haven't found how $A \subset B$ when $1_A(x) = 0$ and $1_B(x) = 1$.

Can somebody please enlighten me ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Assuming $1_A\leq1_B$, can the last case you haven’t figured out how to analyze ever occur?

Comment: The expression “I've managed to show that $A \subset B$ when $1_A(x)=1_B(x)= 1$ and when $1_A(x)=1_B(x)=0$” makes no sense. What is $x$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A,B \subset X$. Suppose $1_A(x)\leq 1_B(x)$ for all $x \in X$. If $x \notin B$ then $1_A(x) \leq 1_B(x) = 0$ so $1_A(x)=0$ hence $x \notin A$. So what can we conclude? If $A \subset B$ then $x \in A$ implies $1_A(x) = 1 = 1_B(x)$ and if $x \notin A$ then  $x \notin B$  or $x \in B$ so we get $0 = 1_A(x) \leq 1_B(x)$ in either case.

Comment: I don't really get how we can have $x \in B$ If $x \notin A$ nor how does that equate to $A \subset B$...

Comment: Correction:  The previous answer was right since $A$ might be a proper subset of $B$. You just consider two cases: If $x \in X$ then $x \in A$ or $x \notin A$. If $x \in A$ then $x \in B$ and if $x \notin A$ then $x \in B$ or $x \notin B$.